# How to handle windows pop up which is not child element of current browser in application with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

I am struggling with problem.
We have 1-2 windows pop up which are not child element of main browser. So
my code returning me "1" as output of SOP below.
and I want to verify content inside that pop up. Can anybody help me here how to handle this situation.

```
String winHandleBefore;
winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

Set<String> winhandle = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator iterator = winhandle.iterator();
String currentWinID;
int num = winhandle.size();
System.out.println(num);
```

Comment: Implement some wait before `driver.getWindowHandles()` using `Thread.sleep()` and then print the size..and let me know the result

Comment: have you tried by using the locator of those pop up windows?

Comment: Hi Noor,I could understand..I have tried by locatior as well..but webdriver does not identify that another pop up which is in browser..it is not working.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Actually i have used wait as well ,but tried with Thread.Sleep(2) ,but still it is not identifying.

Comment: give the html portion of that pop up and the code how you tried to handle the pop up

Comment: <html><head>..</head><BODY onblur=self.focus(); onload="resizeWindow();addPersInfo(1,'  onclick=*javascript:void(openEditPatientWaringForOperation({5935{))*]2016-V class=sheaderb ">Namn</DIV><DIV id=divSearch style="OVERFLOW: auto; "><TABLE ><TBODY><TR class=trBg1><TD style="WIDTH: 25px" vAlign=left nowarp><IMG onclick="editOpReg('../LoginEdit.asp?IsSimplifiedOp=0&amp;nOpId=5336&amp;nType=1', ></TD>
<TD class=sheader><A href="javascript:void(checkClassificationAndPopUp(1,false,1,',-1,66));">2014-02-20 10:57</A></TD></TR><TR class=trBg2></html>

Comment: This is small part of html..because all code pasting does not allow here,Please look into that n let m eknow your thoughts.